# Firebase Dynamic Links with Flutter Automatically Removing Custom QueryParameters while link is being created

Tags: firebase, flutter, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Hello guys I am having trouble with getting parameters from firebase dynamic links and flutter. Even while providing the value at the time of creating links, it is somehow not showing up in the dynamic link. Can anyone help me with the issue? I am stuck for the past two days without any help.

This is the code.

```
class DynamicLinkService {
  String? _linkMessage;

  Future<String?> createDynamicLink(bool short, String? slug) async {
    final dynamicLinkParams = DynamicLinkParameters(
      link: Uri.parse("https://xyz.page.link/"),
      uriPrefix: "https://xyz.page.link/product?prdt=$slug",
      androidParameters: AndroidParameters(
        packageName: "com.example.example",
        minimumVersion: 24,
      ),
      iosParameters: IosParameters(
        bundleId: "com.example.iosexample",
        appStoreId: "13719873",
        minimumVersion: "1.0.1",
      ),
    );

    Uri? url;

    if (short) {
      // final dynamicLink =
      // await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildShortLink(dynamicLinkParams);
      final dynamicLink = await dynamicLinkParams.buildShortLink();
      url = dynamicLink.shortUrl;
    } else {
      final dynamicLink = await dynamicLinkParams.buildUrl();
      // await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.buildLink(dynamicLinkParams);
      url = dynamicLink;
    }

    _linkMessage = url.toString();
    return _linkMessage;
  }

  Future<void> initDynamicLink(BuildContext context) async {

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(
      onSuccess: (dynamicLink) async {
       final Uri? deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;
       var isProduct = deepLink?.pathSegments.contains('product');
       if (isProduct == true) {
         String? slug = deepLink?.queryParameters['prdt'];
         print("2Li $slug");

         if (deepLink != null) {
           if (slug != null || slug != "") {
             context.read<ProductController>().saveSlug(slug!).whenComplete(() {
               Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/ProductDetail");
             });
           }
         } else {
           return null;
         }
       } else {
         return null;
       }
      }
    );

    final PendingDynamicLinkData? data =
      await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    try {
      final Uri? deepLink = data?.link;
      print("1111111, $deepLink");
      var isProduct = deepLink?.pathSegments.contains('product');
      if (isProduct == true) {
        String? slug = deepLink?.queryParameters['prdt'];
        print("2Li $slug");

        if (deepLink != null) {
          if (slug != null || slug != "") {
            context.read<ProductController>().saveSlug(slug!).whenComplete(() {
              Navigator.of(context).pushNamed("/ProductDetail");
            });
          }
        } else {
          return null;
        }
      } else {
        return null;
      }

    } catch(e) {
      print("No DeepLink Found");
    }

  }
}
```

This is the url, which is being created

```
https://xyz.page.link/product?amv=24&apn=com.example.example&ibi=com.example.example&imv=1.0.1&isi=1613285148&link=https%3A%2F%2Fxyz.page.link%2F
```

I tried several ways, but couldn't find a way to get the queryparams.

Help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The query parameters should be in the link (The link the target app will open) rather than the uriPrefix (Domain URI Prefix of your App):

```
link: Uri.parse("https://xyz.page.link/product?prdt=$slug"),
uriPrefix:"https://xyz.page.link",
```